# Why do elite captains walk away instead of killing me?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

In an attempt to get a captain promoted to warchief I tried to get myself killed by an elite captain (the last row before the warchiefs), as a comment to [this answer suggests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185822/how-do-captains-get-promoted-to-warchief/185857#185857). However, when I was beaten, the captain simply walked away saying something about me not being worthy enough for him (if I remember correctly).

At first I thought I made it too easy by not fighting back at all, but I tried it with another elite captain and the first one a second time, hitting them a few times and reducing their health bar before getting killed. But again, both just walked away from the fight and "teleported" to another area. The elite captain I fought twice only said something like "how does it feel being beaten a second time?" and walked away.

When time passes and the changes are shown in Sauron's army, they also don't get a power increase for defeating me.

Why do they decide to let me live? Is this to prevent them from being promoted to warchief?

Comment: I'd appreciate it if the person who downvoted the question could tell me what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular enemy had the "Humiliator" strength.

The text of it says "Does not finish off weak opponents." Perhaps you have to do a certain amount of damage to them before they'll finish you off?

The ign wiki has a [full list](http://www.ign.com/wikis/middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor/Nemesis_Traits) of Nemesis traits.

Comment: Indeed they both have the humiliator strength. What a coincidence, I've died so many times and the two captains I actually want to lose to don't want to kill me :D Thanks :)

Comment: If you beat them up but don't kill them and let them go, they should level up, if that's your goal. I think they have to get to green before they run for it to count.

Comment: On the PC, I've had a Humiliator walk away from me & gain the Revenge flag.  I don't believe he gained a level though.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a grunt to kill you but have him interrupted before he can trigger the last chance(caragor or dominated uruks in the battle), it will default to the closest enemy. If you can make the closest enemy the captain, they will automatically trigger the last chance and kill you.