# Accidentally killed one of the warchiefs in The Bright Lord DLC (Uruk promotions are disabled delibaretly by the developers in that DLC)

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I am playing The Bright Lord dlc. And the current mission is to brand all 5 warchiefs. During the gameplay I have accidentally killed one of the warchiefs which must be branded. But, it seems that developers forgot to take it into the considerations and now I am stucked in the game. None of captains are promoting to warchief. I have done numereous things like deliberately killed by captains so they can promote, advancing the time. But none is worked. I think that there is glitch in the game. As I have searched in the google, promotion system and promotion missions are disabled in that DLC.
Is there any way to solve that problem? Because, I dont want to restart the dlc.
Thanks.

**The question in the comment is about the main game, not the DLC**.

Comment: The accepted answer from [How do Captains get promoted to Warchief?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185822/how-do-captains-get-promoted-to-warchief?rq=1) applies to the "The Bright Lord" DLC.

Comment: @Ramhound no. No. No. In this dlc they have changed nenesis system. I am 100 percent sure that you are wrong

Comment: Having played the DLC recently, and having done exactly the same thing as you did, and doing exactly what the answer suggested I can confirm I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Ramhound really? Very interesting. Because as I see and know there is not these type of missions in that dlc. No duel, no betrayal, no requirement and so on. There is not such missions on the map. You canumt even command to branded captains in that dlc.

Comment: @Ramhound. Are you sure? I have found in google one gamer with dame problem and he was recommeended to restart the dlc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have given up. There is no way to solve the glitch. Only way is to restart the dlc. You must press X button for restarting the dlc. I have restarted it and finished in 2 hours.
I am using Xbox One version of the game.

This link also confirms that there is no other solution:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/241930/discussions/0/613958868352208879/

Answer (score 2):

As of January 24, 2022, it's possible to get all 5 warchiefs branded if you accidently kill one. It's extremely time consuming, but you have to allow yourself to die in order to get new uruks promoted into the warchief slot. no, they cannot already be branded because branded uruks won't attack you.

A captain who kills you will be promoted to warchief. Then go find them again and brand without killing. Be mindful of your already branded uruk army as they have the ability to also kill the warchief forcing you to get another promoted. I found it best to kill the nearby army (press K) when the warchief is brandable in order to prevent the accidental death.