# How can I brand a fifth War Chief?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

My current quest is to brand five War Chiefs, but as you can see I only have 4 available and they're all branded already.

How can I progress my game? Do I need to command an uruk to become the fifth war chief, if that's possible.

I am unsure of how to progress at this stage.

Each of the dominated war chiefs has a mission, which just summons them. As they're branded they just stroll up to me and I can grab them and dominate them again. Then once I've dominated them the mission just lights up again and I can repeat it.

[image: 4 of 5 war chiefs]

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185822/how-do-captains-get-promoted-to-warchief)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in the course of play I've completed another side mission or two, and that seems to have advanced the game.

I now have a new war chief to find and brand. I guess I had completed everything up to that point, and needed a quest completion to push the story onwards.

Comment: From my experience, that's pretty much all you can do. Each objective or quest you complete (or even when you die IIRC) will cause the orc rankings to get redistributed and new ones to take places of the fallen. Became really annoying when on a self-guided mission to destroy the whole army then I die and half of it gets replaced by new ones lol :p

Comment: You can also use advance time to have the same effect.

Comment: My colleague at work tells me that this is the 'last stage' of the game, and you need to clear the other quests, before the story will progress. So I need to complete Torvins questline first.

Comment: @DavidYell that's not true. You can brand all the warchiefs before doing Torvin and Lithariel's quests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for another Uruk to be promoted.

The easiest way is to choose the "Advance Time" option on a forge tower.
The same thing will be triggered if you die. Alternatively, continue playing and promotions will slowly trickle in.

If you manage to brand the remaining captains before the promotion happens, you're guarenteed a free branded warchief.